# Spring Batch remore partitioning add slaves runtime

Tags: java, performance, openshift, spring-batch, partitioning

We are processing few milion of records with spring batch remote partitioning approach. We are using Openshift to deploy master and slaves in a separated containers in order to be able to run multiple slaves. If we starts 2 slaves and run the master with gridsize of 10, each slave process 5 pices of work, which is fine. We tried to increase the number of slaves after the master is started and durring the rest two slaves working, but the newly started slave do not take work. My question is, do we miss something so our new slave not get work?

Comment: In a remote partitioning setup, the master sends `StepExecutionRequest`s to a configurable queue. If you configured your workers as listeners on that queue, they should pick up work regardless if they have been started before or after the master. So I can't see why the newly added workers don't take work in your case. Please share your master/worker configuration to be able to help you.

Comment: We have followed Manella's example shared in https://github.com/mminella/java-remote-partitioning,
 but we are using ActiveMq instead rabbit.
Actually when i run the same test locally, everything is fine. The newly started slaves are getting work immediately. So i believe that, it is something environment/openshift specific.
I will investigate in that direction and will get back if needed.
Thank you @MahmoudBenHassine